# Get raw data from shapefile in C#

Tags: c#, shapefile, dotspatial

I want to get a list/array from a shapefile in C#. Like when you use an online shapefile to csv converter but of course not converted in csv but just as an array of strings. I saw some people recommend DotSpatial but I find it very hard to find documentation. I don't want to draw shapes or any other complicated stuff.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In DotSpatial You can easy read data like this:

```
using DotSpatial.Data;

Shapefile sf = Shapefile.OpenFile(Path);
System.Data.DataTable dt = sf.Attributes.Table;
List<ShapeRange> sr = sf.ShapeIndices;
DotSpatial.Data.IFeatureList features = sf.Features;
```